# Asp.NET MVC : Error while trying to call delete controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Here is a portion of my razor code

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DeleteBeacon", "Beacons", new { beaconId = Model.ID, instId = Model.InstID, pageNo = (int)ViewBag.pageNumber }, new AjaxOptions { LoadingElementId = "imgloaderIndex", OnSuccess = "OnSuccessDelete(data)", OnFailure = "OnFailureDelete(data)" }))
```

Here is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult DeleteBeacon(UserProfile userInfo, long beaconId, long instId, int? pageNo)
    {
        bool status = false;
        int pNumber = (pageNo ?? 1);          
        ViewBag.pageNumber = pNumber;
        try
        {
            status = blBeacon.DeleteBeacon(beaconId, userInfo.UserID, userInfo.SessionToken, null);
            if (status)
            {
                return Json(new { status = "success", pageNumber = pageNo, instId = Convert.ToInt64(TempData["InstituteId"]) });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { status = "failure" });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            LogUtil.Error("BeaconsController\\DeleteBeacon:\n" + exp.Message);
            return Json(new { status = "failure", message = exp.Message });
        }

    }
```

It works fine in local server , but when hosted on production server, I'm getting error while trying to delete. Error is

```
POST https://portal.example.com/Beacons/DeleteBeacon?beaconId=36&instId=9594&pageNo=2 500 (Internal Server Error) 
Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

**UPDATE:** i dug a bit deeper and it shows `data is not defined in OnFailureDelete(data)` which means the POST call is failing but why ??

can any one suggest what may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you don't need to pass `data` in the OnSuccess and OnFailure calls.

```
... { LoadingElementId = "imgloaderIndex", OnSuccess = "OnSuccessDelete", OnFailure = "OnFailureDeleteenter code here"
```

The JavaScript for those should have `data` declared though e.g.:

```
function OnSuccessDelete(data) { //... }
```

EDIT:

I'm unable to replicate your issue. However, here is my working example code, in the hope that it might be of some use to you:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteBeacon(object beaconid, object instid, int pageno)
{
    return Json(new { result = "Hello" });
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DeleteBeacon", "Home", new { beaconId = 1, instId = 2, pageNo = 3 }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "OnSuccessDelete", OnFailure = "OnFailureDelete" }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Click Me"/>    
}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnSuccessDelete(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }

        function OnFailureDelete(data) {
            console.log("Failure " + data);
        }
    </script>
```

To call `OnFailureDelete()` you must set the response status to code to something other than 200 e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteBeacon(object beaconid, object instid, int pageno)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    return Json(new { result = "Hello" });
}
```

Comment: I have used it on several other places and it works fine

Comment: JavaScript declared doesn't have data declared(but some other variable) but as i said it works fine in all other places

Comment: Did you state that you have tried removing `data` from `AjaxBeginForm` and trying that on the failing server?

Comment: Right, I'm just seeing if I can repro this issue.

Comment: Have you got [HttpPost] attribute on your action method `public ActionResult DeleteBeacon`?

Comment: no i haven't but it works in all other places. And ya i tried that too.